# A proof for why the "minority charge carrier concentration along the x-axis in a pn junction isn't constant " confuses the hell out of me

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

I've been following Behzad Razavi's Microelectronics book. Here is the particular excerpt from the book which is confusing

> An interesting question that arises here is: are the minority carrier concentrations
> constant along the x-axis? Depicted in Fig. 2.29(a), such a scenario would suggest that
> electrons continue to flow from the n side to the p side, but exhibit no tendency to go beyond
> x = x2 because of the lack of a gradient. A similar situation exists for holes, implying that
> the charge carriers do not flow deep into the p and n sides and hence no net current
> results! Thus, the minority carrier concentrations must vary as shown in Fig. 2.29(b) so
> that diffusion can occur.
> [image]

The initial fig 2.29(a) says that the electrons won't flow beyond x2 as it lacks concentration gradient. But imagine a scenario where an electron from the n-side reaches 'x2' point. Now the e- concentration at this point is higher than the point exactly beside it, right?

Now, won't the e- flow from the 'x2' point to the one beside it due to the difference in concentration?
So, we're having a flow of electrons, right? But Razavi's book says there won't be any flow in this case.

ALSO, I'VE ANOTHER QUESTION.
Why do we even need a concentration gradient for the charge carriers to flow in forward bias? Won't the potential gradient applied across the junction be enough?

Comment: I suggest rereading the passage. The book is arguing along the same line that you are thinking.

Comment: By this logic figure b would then need to be applied to a uniform semiconductor (without a pn junction) but that's just plain wrong!  Your instinct is right that in the neutral region, beyond a few minority carrier diffusion lengths, the minority carrier concentration is constant as in figure a.  There is drift current dominated by majority carriers because of the small gradient in potential from the externally applied voltage.

Comment: " There is drift current dominated by majority carriers because of the small gradient in potential from the externally applied voltage" 
So, that's why diffusion current becomes important for flow of minority carriers ?